# Multiple buffers on the same file

Tags: c, filestream, file-storage

The procedure is as follows.

1. Filtering a huge `File.txt` file ([FASTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) file format if you are interested) by **line by line** through **file streaming** in `C`.
2. After each filtering process, the output is a `filtered_i.txt` file.
3. Repeat steps 1-2 with 1000 different filters.
4. The expected results are 1000 `filtered_i.txt` files, `i` from 1 to 1000.

The question is:

**Can I run these filtering processes in parallel?**

My concern is multiple buffers would be opened in `File.txt` if do parallel. Is it safe to do? Any potential drawbacks?

Comment: "*multiple buffers would be opened in File.txt*". It's not clear what that means. Please show a [mre] to illustrate what that refers to. But in general it is fine to have multiple readers of the same file.

Comment: @kaylum, Thanks for your reminders. I will try to add a minimal example for completeness later. Also, thanks for your tip on `readers` too.

Comment: I'm curious what size the huge file can have. Can you provide an estimate?

Comment: @Ely About 1Gb, it could be huge for a txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *best* answer to your problem: here are some potential issues to take into consideration:

- opening the same file multiple times for reading in the same or multiple processes does not pose any problems per se, but you might run out of file handles either at the process level or at the system level.
- if the filters use a lot of RAM for their purpose, running too many of them in parallel may cause swapping, which will significantly slow down the whole process
- if the file is large but fits in memory, it is likely to stay in the cache, so running filters in sequence would not cause I/O delays, but running them in parallel may take advantage of multiple cores.
- conversely, if the file does not fit in memory, running filters in parallel should increase overall throughput, especially if they consume the same area of the file at the same time.
- if the process is I/O bound and filters can consume one line at a time, calling them as functions in sequence in a simple loop in a process that reads one line at a time may be a simple solution. Running multiple such processes in parallel, each handling a subset of all filters can further improve the throughput.

As for all optimisation problems, you should test different approaches and measure performance.

Here is a simple script to run 20 filters in parallel:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..20}; do (for j in {0..50}; do ./filter_$[$j*20+$i+1]; done)& done
```

Comment: 1. Could you be more specific on `run out of file handles`? How many handles could be big for the process or system?  2. Do you mean if the whole file will fit in the RAM or just a single line of the file? 3. The last bullet point is awesome. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against opening a file multiple times in parallel. This puts a lot of strain on the OS, and if all of your threads are streaming at once, your performance is going to drop significantly because of thrashing. You'd be much better off streaming the file serially, even large files. If you do want a parallel solution, I'd suggest having one thread be the "streamer", where you'd read a certain number of chunks from the file and then pass those chunks off to the other threads.

Comment: I see your point of thrashing(Don't know this term before) now, which is exactly where my concern comes from. When you say `streamer`, do you mean read certain lines overhead into a heap? If so, do you have any recommendations for the size of the "streamer"? Will the streamer in general improve or lower the performance?

Comment: @yuw444 Yes, that's exactly what I mean. As for a recommended "heap size", I don't have any specific values, but my suggestion would be to be to size it so that you make as few reads from the as possible. Reading itself isn't terribly expensive, but if you're making a bunch of calls, it can get hefty.

Comment: But wait, I just realized that the times of using `fgets()` wouldn't change even though with the `streamer`.  Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: @yuw444 Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "file streaming", but regarding `fgets`, if you call it with a larger buffer size, then you'll be reducing the number of calls to `fgets`. You should only have one thread calling `fgets` in any case, because file pointers aren't shared across threads and you'd wind up with some weird behavior.

Comment: Even if you only have one thread reading from the file, you still have 1000 filters. even if you do 8 in parallel, you still have different parts of the file flying around in memory, so you'd still thrash in the same way you'd thrash if they all opened the file and directly read from the FS (via the OS' FS cache, I assume).

Comment: Test. Limit the number of parallel files opened to the number of CPU cores you have. Then divide the 1000 filters by the number of cores and hand that many filters to each thread to apply. Record results. Then open the file once and open CPU cores - 1 number of threads and divide the filters up between them -- time it. Finally 1 file open and single threaded and record the results. I suspect the 1 file and CPU cores - 1 threads handling filters has the best chance at being fastest, but any improvement may not justify the added complexity over 1 file 1 thread. (testing will let you know)

Comment: I'm afraid the bottleneck would be writing back the output files to disk. Of course it depends on how "huge" the files are.

Answer (score 0):

In any sane operating system, including all the big ones, it is possible and safe for different processes, or different threads of the same process, to open the same file, in parallel, for reading.

Operating systems also cache the file and perform read-ahead, so if two threads/processes read from the same file, the first one will read from disk, the OS will cache it, and the second one will read from cache.

The main thing you should worry about is to match the level of parallelism to the capabilities of the machine (number of processors, memory size) and requirements of filters (whether the filtering threads are I/O bound or CPU bound, how much memory they consume, etc.).

Note that the memory used by filters is the same memory used by the OS cache to cache the file, so if you take too much memory for the filters, you'll get a sort of thrashing where the OS flushes the cached file and then reloads it every time.